# Prevent mixing up Ids of same base type when passing as arguments

Tags: c#, types, int

I have program with a lot of business logic and I am constantly calling methods and passing ID's (userID, projectID, fooID, barID, etc.) that are all ints. Occasionally I get sloppy and swap the order of the parameters and userID becomes projectID and vice verse.

Is there somewhere I can alter an int so that it can't be passed as an int but I can easily convert it from int to "intB"

I'm looking for something kind of like nullable ints: "int?", but I could have "intA", "intB", "intC" and ocne could only be passed as another if it was explicitly cast.

Does anything like this exist in C#?

Comment: pass your values with [named parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) like `yourMethod(userID: userId,.... `

Comment: you can also create your own Class couldn't you..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I could, but I feel like that is a little heavy for a single attribute

Comment: You can't.  The compiler, jitter and CLR have intimate built-in knowledge of the value types.  Like *int*.  Somehow you are not using IntelliSense very effectively, address that first before writing your own CLR.

Comment: The driving factor here is the order of the parameters in a method. Based on that I think you're using the wrong tool for the job. Just as you can mix up the order with `int`, you could just as easily mix up the order with the custom classes. It won't change anything. I really think you need to consider code analysis tools like FxCop.

Comment: You can use F#, it has units of measure that can help to distinguish different usages of the same type. (Very cool feature if you do physics computations, for example)

Comment: TruthOf42, I've changed title - please see if it matches your intention and edit/revert if necessary.

Answer (score 8):

Make a struct containing the int. SImple like that. Pretty much zero overhead as it will be optimized out.

Comment: +1. @SargeBorsch - I don't think it is problem for this particular type of elements. I can't really see something like `UserID ++` as valid code. I actually consider it beneficial not being able to do things like `UserId + UserId` easily.

Comment: On top, one does not loose the abilit to use operatoes because - guess what, in C# you can define operators for your structs ;)

Comment: Well, there is copy/paste, there are templated you can use for that. And for ID's you will not really need arithmetic ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is messing the parameters up, have you tried using the names of the parameters when invoking the method?

If you have:

```
int Divide(int divisor, int dividend)
{
    //stuff
}
```

you can invoke it this way:

```
int result = Divide(divisor: 3, dividend:2)
```

the order doesn't matter, you can do

```
int result = Divide(dividend:2, divisor: 3)
```

as well

Answer (score 0):

Named Parameters are useful in order to prevent mixed up arguments. Example:

```
CalculateBMI(123, 64);
//becomes...
CalculateBMI(weight: 123, height: 64);
//or...
CalculateBMI(height: 64, weight: 123);
```

Simply put the parameter name in front of the parameter when you call the method. For more info, see [Named and Optional Arguments on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).